# M.2 M key SSD in a B key socket

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-rec

My laptop has two M.2 slots -- one being a “M” key M.2 2280 and one “B” key M.2.

The problem is I have two SSDs that are both "M" key. Is there an adapter or something where I can connect a "M" Key SSD to a "B" key slot?

Answer (score 1):

No-- M key SSDs are built to use four PCIe lanes and B keyed interfaces don't provide this. So you can't use two M key SSDs on the board you describe....

https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/02/understanding-m-2-the-interface-that-will-speed-up-your-next-ssd/

Answer (score 1):

**Practical experience:**

Short answer: yes, it works with simple passive adapter.

Recently I tried with new HP laptop with Intel CPU. This laptop has three M2 slots: one for SSD (M-key 2280), one for Wi-Fi module (E-key 2230) and the last one for cellular modem (B-key 2242 and non-standard 2252).

By using Chinese-made adapter, I inserted M-key 2230 SSD into B-key 2242 slot. It had to use so tricks to fix SSD correctly in place (due to non-standard 2252 primary sizing of this slot). First tried with SSD WD SN770M, which failed to work in this slot, while worked fine in the primary SSD slot. Another SSD Corsair MP600 Core Mini works fine in the same slot.
Probably incompatibility of the first SSD is related to the fact that cellular slot is powered all time, even when laptop is turned off completely (quite suspicious fact by the way).

**Original / theoretical answer is below:**

In general, it's possible to connect M-key SSD to B-key M2 socket, but in practice it depends on the mainboard firmware (UEFI / BIOS) and wiring.

Physically M.2 key-B slot has pins 12-19 removed. Key-M slot has duplicated power, ground and some of third and fourth PCIe lanes signals on these pins.

M.2 key-M has pins 59-66 removed. With key-B slot these pins are used for some "coexistence signals" or UART communication, antenna control signals and SIM card presence signals.

The other pins are mostly straightforward compatible. The only questionable are:

- Pin 5: Ground (Key B) / Fourth PCIe Rx Negative (Key M)
- Pin 7: USB Data Positive (Key B) / Fourth PCIe Rx Positive (Key M)
- Pin 9: USB Data Negative (Key B) / Ground (Key M)
- Pin 11: Ground (Key B) / Fourth PCIe Tx Negative (Key M)
- Pin 23: GPIO (Key B) / Third PCIe Tx Negative (Key M)
- Pin 25: Dynamic Power Reduction signal (Key B) / Third PCIe Tx Positive (Key M)

Two (first and second) PCIe lanes use the same pins for key B and for key M. The same is for PCIe service signals.
Both slots should be compatible in general with PCIe x2 SSDs. There are (at least - were) two-lanes SSDs on the market with both key-B and key-M. For example, Intel Optane M2.
However, some motherboards have M2 key B slot that is connected to SATA only, or motherboard firmware may not be ready to recognise CONFIG_x combination 0-1-0-0 indicating "PCIe SSD" (pins 21, 69, 75, 1).

On the SSD side it should be no problem to work with less amount of PCIe lanes. Some mainboards have only two (or even one!) PCIe lanes connected to M2 slot. SSD should detect such situation and negotiate number of lanes used. I personally have MiniPC based on mobile processor where SSD works only with two PCIe lanes in the M.2 key M slot.

It is possible to find cheap Chinese-made "M2 riser" or "M2 extender" boards on the market (created to use larger SSDs on smaller slots, like 22110 SSD in the slot designed for 2242 cards). They can be used to test slot for compatibility (the quality of such boards could be far from perfect, so buy two or three as some could be broken initially). Just carefully cut extra pins, **isolate** naked conductive traces (nail coat works fine) and make sure that other thin conductive tracks are not damaged and no short-circuit is made. Then insert this board into M2 key B slot and insert SSD into the M2 key M slot on this board - if it works, you may leave this board as an adaptor (if you have enough space) or you may cut pins on SSD itself and insert it directly to M.2 key B slot.

Note: M.2 key-B slots have 2 PCIe lanes max, the performance of SDD is sub-optimal in such slots. However, for many use-cases modern SSD performance is excessive and even reduced performance in key B slot could be more then enough.

Answer (score 0):

You physically can't connect an M key m.2 SSD on a B keyed motherboard. And it will not work while upside down. Modifying an M key m.2 SSD will ruin the transistors.

This is an example why modifying it will make it worse.

https://youtu.be/E1TO38nsMvY